# Publishing an IMO type inequality solution?

Tags: inequality

I was looking for a journal in which a solution for a symmetric inequality occurring in physics (finding minima and maxima of an energy expression)  could be published.

The solution is quite nice and direct (using standard inequalites like for math olympiads), so I wanted it to be visible for the people, but I am not sure where to submit it. Since the problem is quite simple and of course the extrema are known for long time by e.g. analytic methods, standard journals on mathematical physics won't accept it, would they?
Thx!

Comment: first buy Cirtoaje  volume 1   and check for your item   https://www.bookdepository.com/Mathematical-Inequalities-1-Vasile-Cirtoaje/9786139882366

Comment: Very nice literature! From skimming through it I don’t find my problem explicitly stated there (while of course it follows from the results presented). Anyway, my solution is mathematically not very rich, it just gives an easy solution to a physical problem, which might be useful for students etc.

Comment: Update: I published it here: https://emergent-scientist.edp-open.org/articles/emsci/full_html/2023/01/emsci220008/emsci220008.html